# Regex - Words in any order

Tags: java, regex, string

Let's say I have 3 Strings which have to appear multiple times, but differently often.

1. `"ab"` appears exactly 1 time
2. `"cd"` appears exactly 2 times
3. `"ef"` appears exactly 3 times

Let's say they have to be seperated with 1 comma.

It should match something like:

- `ab,ef,cd,ef,cd,ef`
- `cd,cd,ef,ab,ef,ef`

It should **not** match:

- `ab,cd,ef` // too short
- `ab,xx,ef,cd,ef,cd,ef` // xx, is invalid
- `xx,ab,cd,cd,ef,ef,ef` // xx, is invalid

I have found:

```
\b(?=\w*ab)(?=\w*cd)(?=\w*ef)[abcdcdefefef]{12}\b
```

but **I cannot match comma** and **I do not want to add all words with the number of letters at the end** ([abcdcdefefef]{12}), because I need to use this for a lot of bigger Strings.

Thank for helping!

Comment: I didn't get why "ab,cd,ef" is invalid?

Comment: Not enough ocurrences of `cd` (needs 2) and `ef` (needs 3). Regex is pretty awful for this sort of problem. Can you split on commas and put them into a counter `HashMap<String, int>`?

Comment: Because cd has to appear exactly 2 times and ef 3 times.

Comment: Perhaps split on a comma and verify the pairs would be easier

Comment: I could split them on commas. But I thought there has to be an solution, that I only have to check one Regex :d

Comment: Should anyone be interested, this is easy in Ruby (and no doubt in other languages): `str.split(',').tally == {'ab'=>1, 'cd'=>2, 'ef'=>3}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget regex.

```
    Map<String, Long> expectedFreqTable = new HashMap<>();
    expectedFreqTable .put("ab", 1L);
    expectedFreqTable .put("cd", 2L);
    expectedFreqTable .put("ef", 3L);

    String[] words = input.split(",");
    Map<String, Long> actualFreqTable = Stream.of(words)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
                    Collectors.counting()));

    return expectedFreqTable.equals(actualFreqTable);
```

Regex is too complicated, and would be very hard to get right. The above is more verbose, but far easier to maintain and read.

---

***Newer Java:***

```
    Map<String, Long> expectedFreqTable = Map.of(
            "ab", 1L,
            "cd", 2L,
            "ef", 3L);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a combination of lookaheads combined with checking the length of the input string:

```
String[] inputs = new String[] {
    "ab,ef,cd,ef,cd,ef",    // should match
    "cd,cd,ef,ab,ef,ef",    // should match
    "ab,cd,ef",             // too short
    "ab,xx,ef,cd,ef,cd,ef", // xx, is invalid
    "xx,ab,cd,cd,ef,ef,ef"  // xx, is invalid
};
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(inputs);
String regex = "(?=.*ab)(?=.*cd.*cd)(?=.*ef.*ef.*ef)[a-f]{2}(?:,[a-f]{2}){5}";

list.stream().forEach(x -> {
    if (x.matches(regex)) {
        System.out.println("MATCH:    " + x);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("NO MATCH: " + x);
    }
});
```

This prints:

```
MATCH:    ab,ef,cd,ef,cd,ef
MATCH:    cd,cd,ef,ab,ef,ef
NO MATCH: ab,cd,ef
NO MATCH: ab,xx,ef,cd,ef,cd,ef
NO MATCH: xx,ab,cd,cd,ef,ef,ef
```

Comment: @Tim If you replace the main check (`[abcdef,]{17}`) with `[a-f]{2}(?:,[a-f]{2}){5}`, then you can eliminate all the ``\\b`` patterns.

Comment: @Twizzl If the check becomes that complex, then I think [suggestion by ggorlen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60657114/regex-words-in-any-order#comment107315944_60657114) has merit, i.e. split the string on `,`, then build a frequency map (`Map<String, Long>`), and check the resulting frequency counts. If you don't want that, then this is still a viable solution, but the regex will get large. *FYI:* Using a frequency map will perform better.

Comment: Yes, this answer bites the dust in a bad way if your actual problem is to check hundreds of substrings within a larger CSV string.  In that case, it would be better to split up the CSV into a collection and then go from there.

Comment: Even if this worked, it's hardcoded, so the spec changes and you now need 42 `ef`s...

Comment: @ggorlen Yeah, go with [answer by Joop Eggen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60657411/5221149). That's the way to do it for complex and/or changing requirements. Tim, don't delete this answer, it is still a good viable *regex* solution for small fixed checking.

Comment: @Tim You can actually make the regex fit the requirement spec better by using `{}`, i.e. `(?=(?:.*ab){1})(?=(?:.*cd){2})(?=(?:.*ef){3})`